# How check specfied CheckedTextView inside recyclerView while other Unchecked

Tags: android, checkedtextview

I am using `CheckedTextView` in RecyclerView. I have defined only one checkedTextView in xml. And i inflate recylerView with dynamic data from server. Now i want to check only selected CheckedTextView while other unChecked. Only one CheckedTextView should be checked while other should remain unchecked when one is checked.

Here is code that i have written.

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    CategoriesDTO categoriesDTO;
   String categories[];

    public CategoriesAdapter(CategoriesDTO categoriesDTO){
        this.categoriesDTO=categoriesDTO;
    }
    public CategoriesAdapter(String[] categories){
        this.categories=categories;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.categories_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.category.setText(categories[position]);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categories.length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public CheckedTextView category;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            category=(CheckedTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        }
    }
}
```

That's how i am setting it checked but it checked all the CheckedTextView.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category);
                checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + categories[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String url = Constants.URL_BASE_CATEGORY + categories[position];
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(url);
            }
        }));
```

how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because a recyclerview reuses the viewholders, so it is best if you maintain a boolean array(`checkedArray[]`) with the size of categories[] with all elements false initially. Then get rid of your onItemTouchListener. So basically in your `onbindviewholder` just put this-

```
      holder.category.setChecked(checkedArray[position]);

      holder.date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          checkedArray[position] = !checkedArray[position];
          notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `ViewHolder` implement `View.OnClickListener` and then in the ViewHolder constructor place an on click listener on the itemView like this:

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        category=(CheckedTextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
```

Then in your ViewHolder class `@Override` the `onClick` method with something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    ((CheckedTextView) v).toggle();
}
```

You would also want to get rid of the `recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener` that you currently have implemented.
What this is doing is placing an click listener on each individual view holder rather than on the entire recycler view. This allows you to manipulate the view that the particular view holder is holding. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for considering answering but this doesn't really work the way i want it to be. First it doesn't set the checkTextview on first tap. When i tap fro 5 or 6 times then it is checked and it doesn't either changed it's state when other textview is clicked.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I guess I didn't quite understand what it is you wanted to do then!

Comment: can you edit your answer according to it? I have implemented this answer

Comment: I have edited it to something that may work better for you. If that still does not work then I am not sure what would. Hopefully this helps!